# Screen scraping with Nokogiri and Each method returning zero

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm running the following code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=bike&catAbb=sss&srchType=A&minAsk=&maxAsk="

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
doc.css(".row").each do |row|
  row.css("a").text
end
```

The only thing I get returned is `0`. However, when I just run `doc.css(".row")`, I get the entire list of rows from the CL. Why is it returning zero when I use the each method and how do I fix it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You're not doing anything with the text you extract

Comment: It's a work in progress. This is my first time playing with Nokogiri.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.each` doesn't return anything, it's a simple iterator. Perhaps you are looking for `.map`?

This will return an array of the anchor element text:

```
doc.css(".row").map {|row| row.css("a").text }
```

Comment: Good but NodeSet#each really does return 0 for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to issue two different css queries; you can combine them:

```
doc.css(".row > a").map(&:text)
```